# Can I exec a stored procedure inside IIF in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, case, iif

For example:

```
select iif (100 < 200, exec dbo.myProc, 'no')
```

I tried do it in case and couldn't - so how can I do it?

Comment: if(100<200)
begin
exec dbo.myProc 
end
else 
begin
select 'no' 
end

Comment: A SQL Server stored procedure **cannot** be executed inside an `IIF` or `CASE` expression. You need to use "conventional", procedural checking with a regular `IF` and then either execute the stored procedure - or not.

Comment: yes but my problem is that i use it inside select statement (because it is part of insert values to a table)

Answer (score 0):

First declare the variable and then exec the query.

```
declare @strquery varchar(max)=iif(100<200, 'dbo.myProc', 'select ''no''')
exec (@strquery)
```

OR

```
if(100<200) 
begin 
 exec dbo.myProc 
end 
else 
begin 
 select 'no' 
end
```

Comment: but i need to exec it inside select statement. so that i need iif or case. it's one of many parameters that i need to insert into a table.

Comment: You can pass parameters in both the cases.

Comment: it look like:
INSERT INTO [dbo].[myTable] (paremeter1,parameter2,...) select  value1, value2, iif (100<200, exec dbo.myProc, 'no') from customers

Comment: pass the parameters while calling the stored proc. Your insert statement should be inside  the proc. 
For eg, exec dbo.myProc '1','2','3'

Comment: what i mean is: one of the values to insert to the table is the result of the procedure. but this procedure has to ba execute just if some conditions happen. so i need to use iif or case because reulare if cannot be used inside select statement.

Comment: create a function instead of stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You cannot do what you want.  You might *possibly* be able to rewrite the stored procedure as a user-defined function.  However, there are limits on UDFs -- such as not being able to run dynamic SQL -- that might make that impossible.

If the stored procedure returns a constant value or table, then you can store the value in an intermediate table:

```
declare @t table ( . . . );  -- appropriate definition
insert into @t
    exec(dbo.myproc);
```

If the stored procedure needs to be called with arguments based on the value in each row, then -- alas -- the only solution is to iterate through the outer query (perhaps using cursor) and to run the stored procedure on each row.